# Export global styles and assets using angular module federation

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I implemented Webpack 5 module federation in my angular app and was able to import it into another app by exporting the remote module
[webpack.config.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHrXA.png)
However, I'd also like to export the global style sheet so the host app gets all the global CSS. would anyone have any experience with this?

I tried implementing it with an answer that I saw, https://stackoverflow.com/a/70552914/15125666 without success

Comment: @AndreiCristea would you be able to elaborate on your previous answer?